# Kill a postgresql session/connection

Tags: database, postgresql

How can I kill all my postgresql connections?

I'm trying a `rake db:drop` but I get:

```
ERROR:  database "database_name" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There are 1 other session(s) using the database.
```

I've tried shutting down the processes I see from a `ps -ef | grep postgres` but this doesn't work either:

```
kill: kill 2358 failed: operation not permitted
```

Comment: When all other attempts failed, the pgreset gem somehow fixed rails/pg thinking a connection existed, which did not.

Answer (score 1027, accepted):

You can use [pg_terminate_backend()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html) to kill a connection. You have to be superuser to use this function. This works on all operating systems the same.

```
SELECT 
    pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM 
    pg_stat_activity 
WHERE 
    -- don't kill my own connection!
    pid <> pg_backend_pid()
    -- don't kill the connections to other databases
    AND datname = 'database_name'
    ;
```

Before executing this query, you have to [REVOKE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-revoke.html) the CONNECT privileges to avoid new connections:

```
REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE dbname FROM PUBLIC, username;
```

> If you're using Postgres 8.4-9.1 use procpid instead of pid

```
SELECT 
    pg_terminate_backend(procpid) 
FROM 
    pg_stat_activity 
WHERE 
    -- don't kill my own connection!
    procpid <> pg_backend_pid()
    -- don't kill the connections to other databases
    AND datname = 'database_name'
    ;
```

Comment: Note that in Postgres 9.2, procpid is renamed to pid.

Comment: If he was a superuser, couldn't he have `sudo`-ed the kill anyway?

Comment: @ndn A database superuser is not the same thing as an OS level superuser. There is no `sudo` in PG.

Comment: This is the only working answer for many SO questions because it has the `REVOKE` step. You saved someone, one more time I guess !

Comment: I think you can use `SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)` to kill your own connections even if you're not a superuser, however, doing `REVOKE CONNECT ON DATABASE` is probably not the best idea for your own user :)

Comment: This solution does NOT work if you have pgAdmin4 opened and connected to the server. See the answer here for this problem: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11893/force-drop-db-while-others-may-be-connected

Comment: SELECT pg_cancel_backend(__pid__); is a much safer alternative

Comment: @cluis92: pg_cancel_backend() is a different function that does a different thing: It just cancels a current query, but it doesn't kill the database connection. It's not safer, it's just different.

Comment: hi, why is that we are not able to login after executing the above query to terminate all the current users? Now none of my users are able login to the db. The details can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68411306/how-to-login-to-postgresql-db-after-session-kill-for-copy-database

Comment: *This* deserve a coffee

Answer (score 275):

Maybe just restart `postgres` => `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: @Starkers I went through most of answers above, until it dawned on me :)

Comment: @Starkers Yes, especially safe in production under high load ;)

Comment: `brew services restart postgresql` if u have brew

Comment: ultimate solution, thanks. On Windows: type `services` on search bar -> find your `postgresql` service -> click `postgresql` service -> and then click `restart the service` on the left

Comment: Didn't solve my issue, but the idea was sound.

Answer (score 66):

With all infos about the running process:

```
SELECT *, pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity 
WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid()
AND datname = 'my_database_name';
```

Answer (score 29):

MacOS, if *postgresql* was installed with *brew*:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

Source: [Kill a postgresql session/connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection/15094012?noredirect=1#comment80791859_15094012)

Answer (score 19):

Easier and more updated way is:

1. Use `ps -ef | grep postgres` to find the connection #
2. `sudo kill -9 "#"` of the connection

Note: There may be identical PID. Killing one kills all.

Answer (score 14):

OSX, Postgres 9.2 (installed with homebrew)

```
$ launchctl unload -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
$ pg_ctl restart -D /usr/local/var/postgres
$ launchctl load -w ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist
```

If your datadir is elsewhere you can find out where it is by examining the output of `ps aux | grep postgres`

Comment: Or `brew services restart postgresql`

Comment: @PJSCopeland Thanks for the utmost simple solution! I think your comment deserves to be a real answer, thus: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48226667/1097104

Comment: Thanks for that, @JuusoOhtonen. Tell you what though, if you want the reputation from it, you could at least link back to my comment?

Comment: @PJSCopeland Done.

Comment: Had issues with other answers and other similar SO post solutions. Running your `pg_ctl restart -D /usr/local/var/postgres` did the trick! (I didn't even run first or third command).

Answer (score 13):

```
SELECT 
pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM 
pg_stat_activity 
WHERE
pid <> pg_backend_pid()
-- no need to kill connections to other databases
AND datname = current_database();
-- use current_database by opening right query tool
```

Answer (score 13):

If you need to disconnect sessions of a particular user, this helped me:

Check all current connections:

```
select * from pg_stat_activity;
```

Grant a role to your user (not important):

```
set role "db_admin";
```

Kill sessions:

```
select pg_terminate_backend(pid)
from pg_stat_activity
where usename = '*** USER NAME TO DISCONNECT ***';
```

Comment: This is great, just what I needed. The site was down, but my local GUI DB client was still connected! Disconnected that, and I was able to make the change.

Answer (score 8):

This seems to be working for PostgreSQL 9.1:

```
#{Rails.root}/lib/tasks/databases.rake
# monkey patch ActiveRecord to avoid There are n other session(s) using the database.
def drop_database(config)
  case config['adapter']
  when /mysql/
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.drop_database config['database']
  when /sqlite/
    require 'pathname'
    path = Pathname.new(config['database'])
    file = path.absolute? ? path.to_s : File.join(Rails.root, path)

    FileUtils.rm(file)
  when /postgresql/
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config.merge('database' => 'postgres', 'schema_search_path' => 'public'))
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_all("select * from pg_stat_activity order by procpid;").each do |x|
      if config['database'] == x['datname'] && x['current_query'] =~ /<IDLE>/
        ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("select pg_terminate_backend(#{x['procpid']})")
      end
    end
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.drop_database config['database']
  end
end
```

Lifted from gists found [here](https://gist.github.com/1112258) and [here](https://gist.github.com/1112071).

[Here's a modified version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17746382/414376) that works for both PostgreSQL 9.1 and 9.2.

Answer (score 8):

MacOS, if postgresql was installed with brew:

```
brew services restart postgresql
```

UBUNTU,

firstly check with this (kill server which is running in background)

```
sudo kill -9 $(lsof -i :3000 -t)
```

if you  didn't  find  pid  Then  you  just  need to  restart
Postgresql service by command which is mention are as under:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

Answer (score 6):

I use the following rake task to override the Rails `drop_database` method.

`lib/database.rake`

```
require 'active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter'
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    class PostgreSQLAdapter < AbstractAdapter
      def drop_database(name)
        raise "Nah, I won't drop the production database" if Rails.env.production?
        execute <<-SQL
          UPDATE pg_catalog.pg_database
          SET datallowconn=false WHERE datname='#{name}'
        SQL

        execute <<-SQL
          SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pg_stat_activity.pid)
          FROM pg_stat_activity
          WHERE pg_stat_activity.datname = '#{name}';
        SQL
        execute "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS #{quote_table_name(name)}"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Edit: This is for Postgresql 9.2+

Comment: You need to use `pg_stat_activity.procpid` instead of `pg_stat_activity.pid` for Postgres 9.1 and below.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5408501/444774

Comment: This is a great answer! It's better and safer than the Rails default. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'VE SOLVED THIS WAY:

In my **Windows8 64** bit, just `restart`ing the service: **postgresql-x64-9.5**

Comment: That is just doing a restart which is generally not desirable for production environments, killing the hug process is a much more desirable option.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue and the problem was that Navicat was connected to my local Postgres db. Once I disconnected Navicat the problem disappeared.

EDIT:

Also, [as an absolute last resort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/921363/398670) you can back up your data then run this command:

```
sudo kill -15 `ps -u postgres -o pid`
```

... which will kill everything that the postgres user is accessing. Avoid doing this on a production machine but you shouldn't have a problem with a development environment. It is vital that you ensure *every* `postgres` process has really terminated before attempting to restart PostgreSQL after this.

EDIT 2:

Due to [this unix.SE post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8927) I've changed from `kill -9` to `kill -15`.

Comment: In my limited experience with Navicat Lite, simply closing the database or server connection is not always enough. Navicat Lite seems to keep the occasional connection open until the application is terminated.

Answer (score 3):

In PG admin you can disconnect your server (right click on the server) & all sessions will be disconnected at restart

Answer (score 3):

First, locate the PID of the query/connection you want to close (see [How to list active connections on PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435839/how-to-list-active-connections-on-postgresql#27435868))

```
mydb=> select pid, application_name, state, query from pg_stat_activity where application_name = 'myapp';
 pid  | application_name | state | query 
------+------------------+-------+-------
 1234 | myapp            | idle  | 
 5678 | myapp            | idle  | 
(2 rows)
```

Then, closing the connection with the PID you picked like this

```
mydb=> SELECT pg_terminate_backend(1234);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quit postgres and restart it. Simple, but works every time for me, where other cli commands sometimes don't.

Comment: Simple and works! To clarify further quite pgAdmin 4 and restart

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to drop it. Just delete and recreate the public schema. In most cases this have exactly the same effect.

```
namespace :db do

desc 'Clear the database'
task :clear_db => :environment do |t,args|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables.each do |table|
    next if table == 'schema_migrations'
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("TRUNCATE #{table}")
  end
end

desc 'Delete all tables (but not the database)'
task :drop_schema => :environment do |t,args|
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DROP SCHEMA public CASCADE")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("CREATE SCHEMA public")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO postgres")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("GRANT ALL ON SCHEMA public TO public")
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("COMMENT ON SCHEMA public IS 'standard public schema'")
end

desc 'Recreate the database and seed'
task :redo_db => :environment do |t,args|
  # Executes the dependencies, but only once
  Rake::Task["db:drop_schema"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:migrate:status"].invoke 
  Rake::Task["db:structure:dump"].invoke
  Rake::Task["db:seed"].invoke
end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that Haris's Answer might not work if some other background process is using the database, in my case it was delayed jobs, I did:

```
script/delayed_job stop
```

And only then I was able to drop/reset the database.

Answer (score 1):

Remote scenario. But if you're trying to run tests in a rails app, and you get something like

"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "myapp_test" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL:  There is 1 other session using the database."

Make sure you close pgAdmin or any other postgres GUI tools before running tests.

Answer (score 1):

Case :
Fail to execute the query :

```
DROP TABLE dbo.t_tabelname
```

Solution :
a. Display query Status Activity as follow :

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity  ;
```

b. Find row where 'Query'  column has contains :

```
'DROP TABLE dbo.t_tabelname'
```

c. In the same row, get value of 'PID' Column

```
example : 16409
```

d. Execute these scripts :

```
SELECT 
    pg_terminate_backend(25263) 
FROM 
    pg_stat_activity 
WHERE 
    -- don't kill my own connection!
    25263 <> pg_backend_pid()
    -- don't kill the connections to other databases
    AND datname = 'database_name'
    ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm on a mac and I use postgres via `Postgres.app`. I solved this problem just quitting and starting again the app.

Answer (score 1):

Open PGadmin see if there is any query page open, close all query page and disconnect the PostgresSQL server and Connect it again and try delete/drop option.This helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely one of the answers above gave me the idea for solving it in Windows.

Open the Services from Windows, locate the Postgres service and restart it.

Answer (score -2):

For me worked the following:

```
sudo gitlab-ctl stop
sudo gitlab-ctl start gitaly
sudo gitlab-rake gitlab:setup [type yes and let it finish]
sudo gitlab-ctl start
```

I am using:
gitlab_edition: "gitlab-ce"
gitlab_version: '12.4.0-ce.0.el7'

Comment: downvoted, this question is not releated to gitlab

Answer (score -5):

the answer is hidden in one of the comments above: `brew services restart postgresql`