# Is there any way to close database connection after fetch data in moodle

Tags: php, moodle

I am trying to access value from database **in every 2 seconds and simultaneously 50 users**.

My query looks as follows:

```
global $DB;

$curseId = $_REQUEST['crseId'];



if(isset($curseId)){



$qstndetails = $DB->get_records_sql('SELECT * FROM {questions} WHERE courseid=? ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1',array($curseId)); 

$qstnval = array_values($qstndetails);

}
```

**Because of heavy load my data is not loading** and I am continuously fetching it in every 2 seconds.

How can I close data base connection after fetching record?

In case of `Java` we can close object of Connection class. Suppose con is the object then we close connection after fetching data as `con.close();`.

**Is there any way to close database connection after fetch data in `Moodle`??**

**Moodle version - 2.9.1**

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand this correctly, are you performing 50 separate queries in the span of 2 seconds or are you getting 50 records at once every 2 seconds? Judging by your query, it's the first, but I can't be sure.

Comment: @Andrew in every each 2 seconds single query performed by 50 different users from different locations to the same database!!

Comment: Oh, ouch. That sounds like a bummer for the database. Firstly drop the `ORDER BY`, there's only 1 record. No need to have it. I can't tell what you're using from the code. Are you using an ORM, a mapper, some self made thingy? Is it using mysqli, PDO, mysql or what?

Comment: @Andrew Buddy its Moodle thing. I am new to Moodle. I do not know how to handle  close in moodle

Comment: Right, right, good thing I'm paying attention -.- Anyway, `Moodle` uses postgres, and their documentation doesn't specify anything related to closing a connection. However, maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection) will help you out.

Comment: Why do you need to query the questions every 2 seconds?