# Why are there random databases showing up in PGAdmin? All of which have 6 character names

Tags: postgresql

There are several databases appearing on my server with names like "tcnejp" and "oavckm".  We did not create them, and when I attempt to drop them, they are bound to active sessions.

Are these system databases?

Comment: I dont think so. You can check active connections with this https://serverfault.com/questions/128284/how-to-see-active-connections-and-current-activity-in-postgresql-8-4 and kill connection with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection

Comment: You probably got hacked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; I'd suspect that somebody broke into your database.

Use the `pg_stat_activity` view to find out from where the connections come.

When in doubt, edit `pg_hba.conf` to restrict who can connect to which database from where.

Comment: Thanks Laurenz.  we cleaned it up and have tightened up our security.