# How to delete a database in pgadmin

Tags: java, sql, database

When i try to create other database with the name "eCommerce" in pgadmin 4 this message appears

**ERROR: source database "template1" is being accessed by other users
DETAIL: There are 2 other sessions using the database.**

I try to delete the others databases but is not working and appears

**ERROR: cannot drop a template database**

What should i do?

Comment: Stop the two other programs currently using the database and retry?

Comment: How you are creating your database ?

Comment: I try to stop the other database but is not working. I m creating database like = "create" > " Database " , the name "eCommerce" and when i click to "save" the message appears.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You simply need to terminate the connections before deleting the database :)

```
    //Terminate all Connections on HostDB
     SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE datname = 'Database_you_want_to_delete';
```

After that deleting shall work without an further problems.

Edit: For further information please take a look at this thread: [Kill a postgresql session/connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection)

Answer (score 41):

It's impossible to drop a database in pgAdmin4 by right-clicking on it and selecting Delete/Drop from the context menu. Because as soon as you right-click on it pgAdmin opens a connection to that database.

But there is another way in pgAdmin4:

1. Close connections to the databases you would like to delete by right-clicking on it and selecting "Disconnect database..."
2. Left-click on "Databases" (One up in the hierarchy: The folder that contains all your databases)
3. Select tab "Properties" on the right hand side
4. There you can select all your databases you would like to delete and click on the trashcan icon:

[image]

Comment: But i cannot select the required db.

Comment: I just discovered this "feature" of pgadmin34. Pretty stupid that Delete/Drop exists on the right-click menu at all, given it is broken!

Answer (score 4):

**The Simplest Solution**, I think, is **closing opened tabs**

> simply closing any opened tabs related to that database in pgAdmin solves it.

In your case, **2 processes "might" be translated as at most two tabs in pgAdmin related to that database!**

Answer (score 2):

You can not drop the currently open database. Run query `DROP DATABASE db_name;` in `Query Tool` from another database.

Answer (score 2):

0. Close PgAdmin
1. Open a terminal
2. `psql`
3. `drop database [db_name];`

Bonus points:
to create a database:
`create database [db_name];`

Answer (score 0):

Using pgAdmin, I followed @softi's solution but tweaked it a little bit and it worked

First, Close connections to the database(s) you would like to delete by right-clicking on it and selecting "Disconnect database..."

Left-click on "Databases" (One up in the hierarchy: The folder that contains all your databases)

Select "Dashboard" tab on the right hand side and terminate the session(s) of the database(s) you want to delete/drop

Then go to the "Properties" tab (next to the Dashboard tab), then select the database(s) you would like to delete and click on the trashcan icon above the list