# How to kill queries which theirs processes are no longer exists

Tags: postgresql

I run:

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
```

And there are some old queries (which still run on the DB background) which theirs python application doesn't exists (The apps crash or stopped without calling connection close command)

```
State          wait_event   backend_type
Active         null         parallel_backend
```

Is there a way to close all the queries which theirs processes are no longer exists ?

I saw this post:

[Kill a postgresql session/connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5108876/kill-a-postgresql-session-connection)

but I don't want to kill all sessions or connections, because there are some connections which gather and update important data.

I just want to close sessions (and stop queries) which theirs processes are no longer exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know or able to figure it out which are not neccessary, then you can fetch their pids from here.

```
SELECT pid,* FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

And use those pids over here along with dbname to kill those connections.

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
where datname in (<put dbname over here>) 
  and pid in(<put pid over here>);
```

Or simply use the below query to kill idle connections, which are not active.

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid) 
FROM pg_stat_activity 
where datname in (<put dbname over here>') 
  and state = 'idle';
```